# Recursive and iterative DNS queries

Tags: networking, dns

I took a test for a server admin course recently. There was a question that confused me however. I want to know why I didn't get it right. The question was:

> "The typical query one DNS server sends to a root name server is
>   called a(n) _______."

For this question I gave the answer "iterative query", but my answer was marked wrong and "recursive query" was marked correct. However, my textbook says:

> "DNS servers use iterative queries when communicating with each other.
>   In most cases, it is improper to configure one DNS server to send a
>   recursive query to another DNS server. For example, if DNS servers
>   send recursive queries to the root name servers rather than iterative
>   queries, the additional burden on the root name servers would be
>   immense, and probably cause the entire Internet to grind to a halt."

The book and the textbook seem to contradict each other. My instructor however says the test is correct.

Who is correct?

Comment: This question might be better suited to Serverfault for a professional answer. At face value it appears the text book is correct; if they can't explain the clear discrepancy in the textbook, you might want a better teacher.

For what its worth, while capturing packets i watched my recursor make only non-recursive queries to the root servers...only queries requesting recursion are client->server; in fact, all root server response's flags were "No recursion available"

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I move this to Serverfault?

Comment: i flagged it to be moved to serverfault; otherwise i believe you could always delete & repost.